# URL with default port number 443 give the error code 500 [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, port, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

Whenever I try to hit `https://p.test.com:443/uploadedsecure/8c6d436?filename=dS2.jpg` url, I get status code:500 from the server.

whereas it gives me `status code:200` when I request the same URL without the port number `https://p.test.com/uploadedsecure/8c6d436?filename=dS2.jpg`

I tried the same URL in web & android and without removing the port number I get the success code:200

Code snippet

```
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [defaultSession downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@" Response %@", response);
}];

[task resume];
```

It would be a great help, If somebody could point out the mistake

Comment: You don't need the `:443` bit as that's the default port for `https://`. So remove it.

Comment: @Droppy, it works when he removes it.  Read the question.

Comment: @Avi Yeah just saw that and was just about to edit my comment.

Comment: I get the image url with the port number from the server and requesting the url gives me status code:500. Just wanted to understand why it doesn't work with the default port.

Comment: Error 500 would suggest an issue on the server side.  Do you have access to the server log files?

Comment: I have tried your code with both url and i got status code 200 in both case!!!!

Comment: The `:443` redirects, if I'm not mistaken, so perhaps it's redirect handling causing the issue.

Comment: @Droppy if redirection is the cause then it should not work on android or web ? Correct me if you think I am missing something.